# Display Image on Div/Text Overlay

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to reveal an image when I hover over a div or a line of text.

here are some references to the effect I am trying to achieve:

https://randellcommercial.uk/ - plugins.
https://1til1landskab.dk/ - really nice, also it changes background colour too which is cool.
http://adasokol.com/works/ - bit mental, but you get the idea.

[this](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2018/11/27/image-reveal-hover-effects/) is what I have been basing my efforts off. however, it seems there is so much unnecessary code. I've been trimming it down and ended up with [this](https://codepen.io/joseph-lion/pen/vYNWWQq). However, it's no good. it's glitchy and feels over-engineered.

```js
document.documentElement.className = "js";
var supportsCssVars = function() {
  var e,
    t = document.createElement("style");
  return (
    (t.innerHTML = "root: { --tmp-var: bold; }"),
    document.head.appendChild(t),
    (e = !!(
      window.CSS &&
      window.CSS.supports &&
      window.CSS.supports("font-weight", "var(--tmp-var)")
    )),
    t.parentNode.removeChild(t),
    e
  );
};

{
  const mapNumber = (X, A, B, C, D) => ((X - A) * (D - C)) / (B - A) + C;

  const getMousePos = (e) => {
    let posx = 0;
    let posy = 0;
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
      posx = e.pageX;
      posy = e.pageY;
    } else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
      posx =
        e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      posy =
        e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    return {
      x: posx,
      y: posy
    };
  };
  // Generate a random float.
  const getRandomFloat = (min, max) =>
    (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(2);

  class HoverImgFx2 {
    constructor(el) {
      this.DOM = {
        el: el
      };
      this.DOM.reveal = document.createElement("div");
      this.DOM.reveal.className = "hover-reveal";
      this.DOM.reveal.innerHTML = `<div class="hover-reveal__inner"><div class="hover-reveal__img" style="background-image:url(${this.DOM.el.dataset.img})"></div></div>`;
      this.DOM.el.appendChild(this.DOM.reveal);
      this.DOM.revealInner = this.DOM.reveal.querySelector(".hover-reveal__inner");
      this.DOM.revealInner.style.overflow = "hidden";
      this.DOM.revealImg = this.DOM.revealInner.querySelector(
        ".hover-reveal__img"
      );

      this.initEvents();
    }
    initEvents() {
      this.positionElement = (ev) => {
        const mousePos = getMousePos(ev);
        const docScrolls = {
          left: document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
          top: document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop
        };
        this.DOM.reveal.style.top = `${mousePos.y + 20 - docScrolls.top}px`;
        this.DOM.reveal.style.left = `${mousePos.x + 20 - docScrolls.left}px`;
      };
      this.mouseenterFn = (ev) => {
        this.positionElement(ev);
        this.showImage();
      };
      this.mousemoveFn = (ev) =>
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          this.positionElement(ev);
        });
      this.mouseleaveFn = () => {
        this.hideImage();
      };

      this.DOM.el.addEventListener("mouseenter", this.mouseenterFn);
      this.DOM.el.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mousemoveFn);
      this.DOM.el.addEventListener("mouseleave", this.mouseleaveFn);
    }
    showImage() {
      TweenMax.killTweensOf(this.DOM.revealInner);
      TweenMax.killTweensOf(this.DOM.revealImg);

      this.tl = new TimelineMax({
          onStart: () => {
            this.DOM.reveal.style.opacity = 1;
            TweenMax.set(this.DOM.el, {
              zIndex: 1000
            });
          }
        })
        .add("begin")
        .add(
          new TweenMax(this.DOM.revealInner, 0.4, {
            ease: Quint.easeOut,
            startAt: {
              x: "-100%",
              y: "-100%"
            },
            x: "0%",
            y: "0%"
          }),
          "begin"
        )
        .add(
          new TweenMax(this.DOM.revealImg, 0.4, {
            ease: Quint.easeOut,
            startAt: {
              x: "100%",
              y: "100%"
            },
            x: "0%",
            y: "0%"
          }),
          "begin"
        );
    }
    hideImage() {
      TweenMax.killTweensOf(this.DOM.revealInner);
      TweenMax.killTweensOf(this.DOM.revealImg);

      this.tl = new TimelineMax({
          onStart: () => {
            TweenMax.set(this.DOM.el, {
              zIndex: 999
            });
          },
          onComplete: () => {
            TweenMax.set(this.DOM.el, {
              zIndex: ""
            });
            TweenMax.set(this.DOM.reveal, {
              opacity: 0
            });
          }
        })
        .add("begin")
        .add(
          new TweenMax(this.DOM.revealInner, 0.3, {
            ease: Quint.easeOut,
            x: "100%",
            y: "100%"
          }),
          "begin"
        )

        .add(
          new TweenMax(this.DOM.revealImg, 0.3, {
            ease: Quint.easeOut,
            x: "-100%",
            y: "-100%"
          }),
          "begin"
        );
    }
  }

  [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-fx="2"] > a, a[data-fx="2"]')].forEach(
    (link) => new HoverImgFx2(link)
  );

  [
    ...document.querySelectorAll(
      ".block__title, .block__link, .content__text-link"
    )
  ].forEach((el) => {
    const imgsArr = el.dataset.img.split(",");
    for (let i = 0, len = imgsArr.length; i <= len - 1; ++i) {
      const imgel = document.createElement("img");
      imgel.style.visibility = "hidden";
      imgel.style.width = 0;
      imgel.src = imgsArr[i];
      imgel.className = "preload";
      contentel.appendChild(imgel);
    }
  });
  imagesLoaded(document.querySelectorAll(".preload"), () =>
    document.body.classList.remove("loading")
  );
}
```

```css
.hover-reveal {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.hover-reveal__inner,
.hover-reveal__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.hover-reveal__img {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.0.1/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="block" data-fx="2">
        <a class="block__link" data-img="https://www.kaspersky.co.uk/content/en-gb/images/product-icon-KSOS.png">Asli</a>
        <a class="block__link" data-img="https://www.kaspersky.co.uk/content/en-gb/images/product-icon-KSOS.png">D24</a>
        <a class="block__link" data-img="https://www.kaspersky.co.uk/content/en-gb/images/product-icon-KSOS.png">Jantung</a>
        <a class="block__link" data-img="https://www.kaspersky.co.uk/content/en-gb/images/product-icon-KSOS.png">Tracka</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/demo.js"></script>
</body>
```

How can I create a simple image reveal on rollover that is clean and simple?

Comment: Just replace the google image by your own or dynamic image.

Comment: Yes @Mr.Jo yes it does, Earlier today I saw this and used it but it was breaking when I added more than 1 instance, on the thread you link too here I can see that there is help for multiple instances. thank you

Comment: I mean this Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HJf8q/2/ But yes, you need to adjust it. If you can't go for this I'll post an answer for your question with a different content.